# How to assign subject name to their proper field

Tags: django, django-models, django-import-export

I have used django-import-export package. And want to have related database from csv file of format,

```
roll_no,student_name,subject_1_mark,subject_2_mark,....subject_n_mark
```

i'm having difficulty of assigning subject mark to their appropriate field on django ORM

example:

```
#csv file
roll_no, student_name, FOCP, IT, OS, DS, DL
201,john,56,34,65,34,68
```

#### Models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    """ Store Student Information """
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    roll_no = models.IntegerField()

class Subject(models.Model):
    """ Store Subject Information """
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    sub_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=True,blank=True)

class Exam(models.Model):
    """ Store Exam Information """
    exam_type = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    exam_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

class Mark(models.Model):
    """ Store Mark Information """
    subject_name = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='marks', null=True, blank=True)
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam, related_name='marks', null=True, blank=True)
    mark = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

#### settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'import_export',
)
```

#### admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export import resources
from .models import Subject

class SubjectResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Subject

class SubjectAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = SubjectResource


admin.site.register(Subject, SubjectAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Fields for mapping 
[Field represent mapping between object field and representation of this field.](http://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_fields.html)

Comment: i am unable to figure out can anyone help me out with small demo please

Answer (score 0):

I override `before_import` and did some additional logic on data that solve my problem. I had opened issue on github https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/644#issuecomment-320966810